# In the solution folder, where should I put the icons?

Tags: visual-studio

Should I put the icons in:

```
[Solution folder]\[Project folder]\Resources\Icons
```

or:

```
[Solution folder]\Resources\Icons
```

or somewhere outside the solution folder?

Thanks

**Update**:

Based on the answers of [Ritch Melton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402547/ritch-melton) and [x112358](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633195/x112358), I decided to put the icons in:

```
[Solution folder]\[MyProject.Views project folder]\Resources\Images
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the question of keeping resources (icons, configuration, etc.) under the solution folder versus under a specific project folder, I usually ask the question: Is it unique to a single project or does it apply to multiple projects? If it's shared, I'll stash it at a higher-level folder than if it's project-specific.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to put them in the project folder, otherwise known as the "project cone" in MSBuild parlance, an then add them to the project from there.